# Testing behavior of a derived class in isolation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I'm attempting to isolate and test a particular class in an existing code base which is derived from some base and has a private class member that I want to mock:

```
public class Derived : Base 
{ 
   protected Something<Other> _otherSomething = new Something<Other>();
}
```

Specifically, I'd like to use the tests to verify that `Derived` raises some event `DoSomething` in response to `_otherSomething` raising the `ItHappened` event.

In an attempt to accomplish this, I created in my test project a `MockedDerived` class which is a `Derived`:

```
public class MockDerived : Derived
{
   public Something<Other> OtherSomething 
   { 
      set { _otherSomething = value; } 
   }
}
```

I'm using **NSubstitute** as part of my MSTest test method to mock out a class and I want to do something like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
   var sub = Substitute.For<Something<Other>>();
   MockedDerived md = new MockedDerived();
   bool wasRaised = false;
   md.DoSomething += (sender, args) => wasRaised = true;
   md.OtherSomething = sub;
   sub.itHappened += Raise.Event<ItHappenedEventHandler<Other>>(new ItHappenedEventArgs<Other>());
   Assert.IsTrue(wasRaised);
}
```

Where I'm having some difficulty is in that there is a fair amount of baggage that the `Base` class brings to the table, namely it creates some objects of other classes and those have some timers and ultimately involve a database.

It gets messy.

And all I really want to do is ensure that this `Derived` class exhibits particular behaviors and responds as expected.

Any suggestions on how to isolate the testing of this `Derived` behavior from the messy `Base` and its various members?  Perhaps I'm just not seeing the obvious solution.

Comment: You need to mock `Base`'s dependencies to get `Derived` under test.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the situation of testing legacy code where your base class takes in concrete dependencies rather than depending on interfaces. You might want to refer to the Sprout method and Sprout classes described in Michael Feather's book "Working Effectively with Legacy Code".

Comment: Thanks for the mention of that book - I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the details of what your code is doing or how much flexibility you have to change what is there, I can think of two rough approaches to try: isolating both `Base` and `Derived` from their common dependencies, or breaking the inheritance chain.

As an example of the former, we could inject the "baggage" causing the problem into `Base` (we'd have to provide that to `Derived` as well). We can then fake that out in a test to keep our test free from timers and databases.

```
public class Base {
  public Base(DatabaseStuff d, TimerStuff t) { ... }
}
public class Derived : Base {
  public Derived(DatabaseStuff d, TimerStuff t, Something<Other> something) : base(d,t) {...}
}
```

For the second option we could try replacing inheritance with composition. Rather than inheriting from `Base`, we could make `Derived` have a reference to a `Base` and delegate to that instead.

```
public class Derived {  //TODO: Rename to `NotSoDerived` 
  public Derived(Base b, Something<Other> something) { ... }
  public ItHappenedEventHandler<Other> itHappened ...;
  public void SomeBaseMethod() {
    b.SomeBaseMethod(); // let b handle this call
  }
}
```

Now we can inject a fake `Base` (or `null` *<shudder>* if your test won't call `Base`) and a mocked `Something<Other>`, and we can test that aspect of `Derived` in isolation.

If you need to use `Derived` and `Base` interchangeably then you could look at extracting an `IBase` interface if that makes sense, and then both `Base` and `Derived` could implement that.

Comment: Thanks for the response - without going into too much detail, Derived was developed as a replacement/wrapper of Base to provide some caching of of data, etc.  It overrides a subset of the functions provided by Base - a minority of the functions.  I guess the downside to the composition route is that each of those functions requires a delegating function in **NotSoDerived** but the upside of this, as you say, is that testing NotSoDerived is simplified because the faked out Base implementation is lightweight and neither knows nor cares about any of that DatabaseStuff and TimerStuff.